# Typing Variable as Function of Generic Type

Tags: typescript

I have a generic function type:

```
type TestType<T extends HTMLElement> = (input: T) => React.Ref<T>;
```

I have a variable, which I would like to be typed with that type, so that I have strong type guarantees for the return type:

```
const Test = (input) => {
  return React.useRef(input);
}
```

I cannot figure out to apply this type to this variable (`Test`)

Things I have tried:

1. Being as explicit as I can:

```
export const Test: TestType<T extends HTMLElement> = <K extends HTMLElement>(input: K) => {
  return React.useRef<K>(input);
}
```

- This fails to compile with, among other error messages, `"Cannot find name 'T'."`

  2. Trying to let Type Inference help me out

```
export const Test: TestType = (input: K) => {
  return React.useRef(input);
}
```

- This, unsurprisingly, fails because `TestType` requires a type argument

When I look at the TS documentation, the closest I can find is this snippet:

```
interface GenericIdentityFn {
    <T>(arg: T): T;
}

function identity<T>(arg: T): T {
    return arg;
}

let myIdentity: GenericIdentityFn = identity
```

but I can't find any way of passing type information to the variable declaration and having TS infer the type of the function argument (`input`) or the return type (though in this case it's easy enough for TS to infer it from the implementation).

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? `interface TestType { <T extends HTMLElement>(input: T): React.Ref<T> }` and then `const Test: TestType = <K>(input: K) => React.useRef<K>(input);`

Comment: I feel like you don't need the <T extends HTMLElement> in the type declaration. A simple type `TestType = (input: HTMLElement) => React.Ref<HTMLElement>;`. Since you know T extends HTMLElement you actually don't need it, typescript will accept any instance of HTMLElement or of classes that inherit from it.

Comment: @AlekseyL. - Yes! Feel free to post as an answer. Perhaps a trivial one in the end, but I was not able to piece it together myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you were in right direction. First define the interface with [call signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types):

```
interface TestType {
    <T extends HTMLElement>(input: T): React.Ref<T>
}
```

Now you can use it to type the variable:

```
const Test: TestType = <K>(input: K) => React.useRef<K>(input);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUkBnGFgTzGYG9ycYXAA8LOEgAedagBN2cABIsAsgBkAogBskIJLQB8AChpgArjABcrAJQ3k6GADpkmcYfIBfSmgjVOVg5rIM4ePjgAXjEAaRMzSxsY2yjDRGIXc3YkN1E402oLGFtSIA)

---

Not sure what's the use case, but you could also specify return type explicitly without defining the type for whole function:

```
const Test = <T extends HTMLElement>(input: T): React.Ref<T> => React.useRef<T>(input);
```